# Doesn't GHDL support infinite clock generation in testbench?

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I'm having a problem with a clock generation in GHDL. I'm trying to simulate an infinite (in terms of simulation time) clock, but the command in GHDL to analyze (-a) the VHD got stucked. Here is the code:

```
    library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;

--entity--
entity clock_ex is                   
-- nothing inside because is only an example of clock process VS clock event     
end clock_ex;

-- Architecture --

architecture CLKEX of clock_ex is

signal clk_p: std_logic :='0'; -- clock for process 2ns semiperiod
signal clk_e: std_logic :='0'; -- clock for event   1 ns

begin

clk_e <= not clk_e after 1 ns; -- change in the clock trough event
process
begin
clk_p <= not clk_p; -- change in the clock trough process
wait for 2 ns;
end process;

end;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to generate 2 clocks, with semiperiods 1 and 2 nanosecond respecetively, one in a concurrent way (activated by event) one in a sequential way (inside a process). In that way, the analyze got stucked. But if I modify the process in this way:

```
    process
variable stop_s: integer :=100; -- to stop the process
variable count_s: integer :=0; -- counter integer 
begin
if(count_s < stop_s) then 
clk_p <= not clk_p; -- change in the clock trough process
count_s:= count_s+1; -- change in the clock trough event
wait for 2 ns;
end if;
end process;
```

GHDL is able to analyze (-a) and elaborate (-e) the file. When I run it (with -r), with the option to add the CVD, the shell got stucked too, but this time the CVD is generated, and I can anlyze it with GTKWave, and the bheavior is correct according to the variable stop, the execution is stopped at 200 ns.

I would like to know if the first example has problem itself or if GHDL doesn't support the infinite clock generation.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know what is the issue with GHDL. The code got simulated in my Xilinx ISE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's really stopping at the analyze, `ghdl -a` stage, then I have to ask what version of ghdl you are using.

Using GHDL 0.34dev, it compiles (analyzes and elaborates) fine, and sticks at the `ghdl -r` stage. If your ghdl version is earlier than 0.33, upgrade it from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ghdl-updates/?source=directory) or [Github](https://github.com/tgingold/ghdl).

If it sticks at `ghdl -r`, it sounds like ghdl is doing exactly what you ask, the executable is running forever. You have written a test with an infinite runtime and that's exactly what you get.

Try `ghdl -r clock_ex --help` to see further runtime options, and `ghdl -r clock_ex --stop-time=1us` to stop the simulation after 1 us simulation time.

Comment: Hi Brian, thank you for the answer. I don't know what happens before, now the analyze (-a) works. As you suggested, I tried the command --stop-time with as option within -r command, ant it works well. I'm using the 0.33, the last official (the 0.34 is still in prelaunch mode). However, I'm still curios if some commercial ide (like Quartus, ISE or Vivado) are able to handle the "infinite" simulation, or if even there we have to specify a stop time for the simulation; this question arise from the previous comment to my question, in wich the user asserted that in Xilinx ISE the code works.

Comment: ISE simulator has a stop time setting, which has a default value of 1 us.